# Set Thunderbird to Update All Folders

Tags: thunderbird

I use an MSN account for my email, and recently Microsoft updated their Hotmail/Live/MSN accounts for their new Outlook or Exchange platform. This subsequently broke Windows Live Mail connections, but I've been able to get used to Mozilla's Thunderbird mail application. I do have one issue with it though;

The *Inbox* folder will update automatically every 10 minutes. However, I need to click on *Sent*, *Trash*, and *Junk* individually for them to communicate with Microsoft's servers, and subsequently update on my client.

How can I get Thunderbird to update all of these folders whenever it checks with the server?